# Trying to Create a Virtual Machine Deployment in Azure via Service Management API

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Trying to Create a Virtual Machine Deployment in Azure via Service Management API.

But getting the 404 http error code , though the uri is correct.I am  correctly setting the values in the below format,

https://management.core.windows.net//services/hostedservices//deployments/

Anything else is missing ? Also am setting the certificates for SSL authentication.All other services seems to work but this alone is throwing a 404 http error

Comment: See also http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/9c6da842-1261-473a-8f13-30fd03f43cda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked.There are some errors in MSDN documentation.

```
uri:https://management.core.windows.net/subscriptionID/services/hostedservices/servicename/deployments
```

No slash at the end, but MSDN documentation gives a slash at the end.

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned you are using this url:

https://management.core.windows.net//services/hostedservices//deployments/

are you inputing your subscription-id and hosted service on which you wish to deploy?

the url should look like this:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<service-name>/deployments/
```

taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194

though when using the above URL i was also getting 404 responses, i needed to remove the trailing slash at the end. (".../deployments" , not ".../deployments/")
after this i started getting BadRequest Responses but this is probably just because of the XML body not being generated properly.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about Windows Azure Virtual Machines. In that case you might not be using the correct newer Powershell cmdlets to create Azure Virtual Machines because when you make new Virtual Machine cmdlets you don't need to use the management URL. It is all done during very first call when you configure connection using PublishSettings file and then set your subscription. The steps to create a new Azure Virtual Machine using Powershell cmdlets are as below:

- Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile ([documentation is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156055.aspx))
- Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile *azuresettings*.publishsettings
- New-AzureVM ** ([documentation/sample script is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152815))

If you are using PaaS Windows Azure Web/Worker Role then you will use:

- New-AzureDeployment  ([documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152867))

A list of all new Windows Azure Powershell CMDlets is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841).

Comment: Is it Azure Cloud Service or a Azure Virtual Machine?

Comment: But we want to integrate this functionality into our java app . So where does cmdlets play a role in integrating with a java app ??